# Adding HTTPS to a website

Tags: ssl, https

I have a website (http://app4u.ml/, that resides in Ubuntu) with Tomcat installed on it. Via HTTP, everything works great.
I tried adding to the site  HTTPS.
I downloaded a self-signed certificate from http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ and put the '.cert' and '.key' in the server in `/etc/ssl/localcerts` and '.crt' file in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla.`

Then, I ran on Putty:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.crt -keyout /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.key
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml*
```

Then, I added to the 2 files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` the values of:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.key
    ServerAdmin info@app4u.ml
    ServerName app4u.ml
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and ran: `sudo a2enmod ssl` and then `service apache2 restart`.
This made trying to get the site in HTTPS throw a warning in chrome. If I tried to continue, I saw an empty folder list (but it had values in it if I tried to go to it in plain HTTP). Also, trying to contact the Tomcat on the server throws

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

What have I done wrong? What is missing?

**EDIT2:** Further problems - Now my tomcat work for GET requests, but not POST. For POST requests I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed`. Why?

Comment: Self-signed certificates cannot be verified by a trusted third-party. That is where the issue lies.

Comment: I tried deleting the .crt file from /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla, but still have problems. What should I do?

Comment: Purchase a proper trusted SSL cert.

Comment: Don't use self-signed certificates for public websites. Have a look at let's encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/
To set it up with apache have a look at CertBot: http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Cacerts is also a good place to have a look (i don't work for them)

Comment: I tried everything on https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-apache but still the HTTPS site is not loaded. Should I delete stuff from my previous try?

Comment: What does your .vhosts file looks like now?

Comment: I looked in /etc/apache2/sites-available but haven't seen any .vhost file, only two .conf files.

Comment: Also - must I purchase a certificate? Aren't there any free ones?

Comment: @Ran letsencrypt.org provide free certificates.

Comment: @Tom I tried everything on certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-apache but still the HTTPS site is not loaded. Now I try https://gethttpsforfree.com/ but on step 3 it says: Error: Account registration failed. Please start back at Step 1. { "type": "urn:acme:error:malformed", "detail": "JWS verification error", "status": 400 }. Isn't there somewhere a good guide?

Comment: Maybe https://community.letsencrypt.org/ can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct Apache to forward (proxy) requests to Tomcat. The documentation is pretty complete but the following should get you in the right direction (it's not totally possible to give you cut&paste directions since it depends on exactly what you want and what you have):

Run this:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

And put that in your config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/app4u.ml.key
    ServerAdmin info@app4u.ml
    ServerName app4u.ml

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have 2 files in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Should I put it in both of them? What is a command and what should be in the file?

Comment: You have to put it in the appropriate file and you have to make sure the site is enabled - `a2ensite xyz`. Sorry, I don't have your server in front of me so can't give copy/paste commands, you have to have some understanding of Apache to configure and run it.